# hdfs namenode -format Error: Could not find or load main class Abdul

Tags: java, hadoop

Windows 10:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

>hdfs namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class Abdul

Environment variable :
HADOOP_HOME
C:\hadoop-2.8.0\bin

JAVA_HOME
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

path
C:\hadoop-2.8.0\bin
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
C:\hadoop-2.8.0\sbin

hadoop-env.cmd

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
```

Comment: I don't think `Abdul` is a Hadoop program. What is your Windows user name? `Abdul ??`

Comment: I think your problem is that your user name has spaces in it. I think that you will find that this break a lot of software. Hadoop is not yet completely "Windows-ized".

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue as i configure the **JAVA_HOME & HADOOP_HOME** in my system variable path.
Basically problem is **hadoop-env** file where it pick your username as Admin configure your system your name with space which cause issue .
For me it work when i have change in hadoop-env.cmd file .

You will find **hadoop-env.cmd** inside **cd %HADOOP_HOME%/etc/hadoop/** edit this file at the end of the file you will get **HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME%** .
Just change as per below instead of **myuser** you write **your name without space( )** and save it and start new cmd.

**@rem set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME%**

**set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=myuser**

Comment: I could resolve this when I ran as administrator. But when using my user account, the error is still there. Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

Abdul is windows user name.

I posted the message again

C:\Users\Md. Abdul Latif>hdfs namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class Abdul

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3lvi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache Hadoop documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) in section 'Choose target OS version', Windows 10 is not yer suppoted:

> The Hadoop developers have used Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server
>   2008 R2 during development and testing. Windows Vista and Windows 7
>   are also likely to work because of the Win32 API similarities with the
>   respective server SKUs. We have not tested on Windows XP or any
>   earlier versions of Windows and these are not likely to work.

It is recommended that you use a Windows supported version.